# Browser-Independent Client HTTP Resource Timing Measurement Tool

Tags: http, google-chrome, networking, latency, measurement

I am looking for a stripped-down version of [Chrome's interface](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#resource_network_timing) to the [W3C Resource Timing](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) API.

I would like to programmatically measure the http request latency of a single object in a way that distinguishes between the DNS lookup, TCP connection, and time between sending the request and receiving the query. I'm looking for a browser-independent solution so that I can easily log the results in a database.

See for example, the network timeline view in the Chrome developer window (profile picture).

Related programs include httping and wbox, which measure http request latency but don't split up the response time into separate events.

Does there exist a simple program which fits my needs?

Note: I do not have access to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cURL (version 7.19.0 and up).

```
curl --output /dev/null --silent --write-out "time_namelookup=%{time_namelookup}\ntime_connect=%{time_connect}\ntime_appconnect=%{time_appconnect}\ntime_pretransfer=%{time_pretransfer}\ntime_redirect=%{time_redirect}\ntime_starttransfer=%{time_starttransfer}\ntime_total=%{time_total}\n" --url http://curl.haxx.se/ds-curlicon.png
```

Explanation of the timers can be found on the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and [here](http://blog.thousandeyes.com/measuring-performance-with-http-proxies/).